# Best way to get a set of friends' names: javascript or server?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm writing some code to handle an application invitation request (FB.ui, method = apprequests), and would like to show the user, after sending the invitation, a block containing the pictures and names of the users to whom the request was sent.  It appears that the only way to do this is to get the names of all the users's friends via an API call to /me/friends and chew through the returned object, pulling the names for each invited user.  C'est la guerre.

I've got some code doing this, but I'm worrying a little about performance in the case where the user has a large number of friends -- /me/friends will return up to 5000 friends without calling the 'next' link; Facebook says that the average user has around 120-130 friends.  It seems like there are two ways to deal with this:

1: Do it all in the browser, in Javascript; this is surely the most straightforward, but I worry about the efficiency of the Javascript implementation(s) in dealing with large numbers of friends -- it would have to deal with a pretty large object containing all the friends, and would spend a lot of time searching through that large object looking for the right ones.

2: POST the list of invitees over to my server, which would make the call to FB to get the friends and construct and return the list of user names.  My gut says that the server would be a more competent (= faster, less prone to locking up) engine for doing this stuff, perhaps enough so that it would be worth the cost of making the call from javascript over to the server and back again.

But, to be honest, I don't really know.  Any opinions out there, hopefully informed ones?  I could do it either way, but if there's something resembling a best practice, I'd like to follow it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to query /me/friends.  When you make the FB.ui call, there is a callback containing the request_id's and (more importantly in this case) the fbid's of the users that were invited.
You can search for that user directly simply with a call to :
`https://graph.facebook.com/{FRIEND_FBID}`.
These calls, even with FQL are relatively small and you shouldnt have to worry about performance.  Ajax calls with the Javascript SDK would work fine, as would posting the request parameters to your server, and executing them there.
They do take some time... but nothing u really have to worry about.

---

If your `apprequests` are being used for in app notifications, then you'll probably have a database set up and store your users referenced by their FBID you could also query your own database and retrieve the names, profile pictures that you saved on the users first visit.

Comment: This helps; thanks!  I now have to put on my semi-newbie hat and ask how to make the call to https://graph.... I can see that working in Graph API Explorer; from javascript, I've tried $.get("https://graph.facebook.com/THE_UID", function ...), but I get an error with XMLHttpRequest refusing to load the URL (cross-domain problems?).  Trying FB.api(THEUID, function ...) gets me a basic Facebook object -- uid, gender, and some other stuff, but not the name.  Can you clarify, please?

Comment: Well you're already halfway there with your `apprequest` call...
Here is a link to the [javascript sdk api call documetation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/)

Comment: That's what I've been following, and it's not giving me the name.  If I run (for instance) FB.api("THEUID", function (the_result) { console.log(the_result); alert(the_result.name) });, the value of the_result showing up in console.log has a number of correct properties, like gender and id, but name is not one of them.  (By the way, FB.init(...), with some appropriate parameters, has been called before this runs.)  Any insights?  Do I need to get an access token in there as an explicit part of the call?

Comment: You might want to read a bit more on [facebook permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/); you'll need the correct permissions to view information about a users friends.

Comment: Solved, in a manner of speaking. In the request handler, I need to call back to my server to save the request IDs in the DB so I can clear them when/if the user authorizes the app.  Over there, calling file_get_contents on graph.fb.com/uid worked just fine, so I could get the user names, pair them with their IDs, pass the whole thing back via JSON, and let the JS do its thing. I was never able to get the FB.api calls to give me the user names, but thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You can immediately do another request once you send the app request. This is how we're doing it in a Facebook application that we're building:

```
FB.ui(app_request_options, function(response) {
  if (response && response.request_ids && (! response.error)) {
    //Make another call to get the profile information
    FB.api('', {"ids" : response.request_ids.join(',')}, function(response2) {
      if (response2 && (! response2.error))  {
        for (request_obj in response2) {
          //Do stuff... Update UI, post back to server, etc.
        }
     }
 }
```

We're posting that information back to a server, but you could just update the UI with the the name, profile picture, etc.